# Conect Adobe Flash to C#/SQl Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to develop a DISPLAY SYSTEM (PIS:Passenger Information System).Let me explain the problem .

[image]

The  system includes LCDs that is located in Stations of Metro.The passenger can see the graphically movement of the trains .the sensors sense the train and send the information to our database .this information should be displayed on the LCD and the passengers can see the trains location and arrival time on the LCD,but where is my problem ?!!my project manager said to me the information should be displayed on the LCD using Adobe Flash .but my problem is how can send the information to `SWF` file .i googled it and i found i can use `webservices` but in fact i couldn't find any useful article about this could you please give me some help and method about this .

I should display the movement of trains of lcd ,so i should send the an array to swf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variety of options

1. Using URLLoader, which is basically AJAX sending text. You'd have to poll to the server though regularly. Any backend should be fine for this.
2. You could use AMF, which works similar to the option above. But binary data is send over HTTP, so it's more efficient, but the backend has to understand AMF as well.
3. You could use sockets, providing a simple two communication. The backend needs of course to be a socket server.
4. You could use web-sockets, which is basically the new cool way for full duplex communication. The backend has to implement the websockets protocol though. I used `ws` in the passed and was quite satisfied.
5. You can use SOAP based web services, but that is way to heavy and requires using Flex, if you want to use them out of the box.

My suggestion would be a simple REST server which gets accessed via URLLoader. In the ActionScript language reference, you find examples, which are sufficient for the client development.

On the other hand ... if the backend is already set up, ask the backend guys how to access the data - I mean the protocol - and implement the client with regards to the protocol being provided.

Comment: Thank you Dear friend do you have any example of your suggested method ?

Comment: An example using the URLLoader can be found in the language reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html